# Problema con if y &&

Tags: c++

Buen día!

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio que encontré:

Escribir un programa en C++ , que determine la eficiencia energética de una Termoeléctrica, considerando su **consumo en general** en 10000 kW. Si su consumo ingresado esta entre el 80% y el 100% kW visualizar “**CONSUMO MEDIO**”, en caso contrario que sea superior al 100%, visualizar “**ALTO CONSUMO DE ENERGÍA**”.

Quise agregar también un mensaje por si el consumo es menor a 80 pero el programa no me está funcionando bien.

Si pongo 80, en lugar de imprimir "**CONSUMO MEDIO**" imprime "**CONSUMO BAJO**" y no encuentro cómo corregir este problema. Espero puedan ayudarme, por favor.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  float consumoGeneral = 0;
  float consumo = 0;

  cout << "\t\tEficiencia Energetica" << endl;
  cout << endl << endl;
  cout << "Para determinar la eficiencia energetica \ningrese el Consumo "
          "General (en kW): ";
  cin >> consumoGeneral;
  cout << endl;
  cout << "Ahora ingrese el consumo a comparar: ";
  cin >> consumo;
  cout << endl;

  if ((consumo >= 0.8 * consumoGeneral) && (consumo <= consumoGeneral)) {
    cout << "CONSUMO MEDIO";
  } else if (consumo < 0.8 * consumoGeneral) {
    cout << "CONSUMO BAJO" << endl;
  } else {
    cout << "ALTO CONSUMO DE ENERGIA";
  }

  cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

Gracias de antemano!

---

Cerré el programa y lo volví a abrir y me sigue dando lo mismo :(

[image: Codigo y error]

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de qué el programa se está compilando? A mí me funciona https://ideone.com/qTbays

Comment: Sí, de hecho creé un nuevo proyecto y da lo mismo, creo que es un problema de code::blocks.

Comment: He añadido un cometario en el chat para una posible prueba.

Comment: Prueba haciendo que imprima el valor de "consumoGeneral" por 0.8
Te ayudará a saber si el error está en el if o en la multiplicacion

Answer (score 4):

o yo no entendi bien o su programa hace lo que pide, quizas deba de revisar que esta ejecutando un build actual y no uno antiguo le dejo la salida que obtengo en un ideo online y pienso que hace lo que pide.

---

- Consumo General -> 100
- consumo -> 80

```
        Eficiencia Energetica


Para determinar la eficiencia energetica 
ingrese el Consumo General (en kW): 100

Ahora ingrese el consumo a comparar: 80

CONSUMO MEDIO
```

---

- Consumo General -> 100
- consumo -> 78

```
    Eficiencia Energetica


Para determinar la eficiencia energetica 
ingrese el Consumo General (en kW): 100

Ahora ingrese el consumo a comparar: 78

CONSUMO BAJO
```

---

update, me acabo de fijar que use 80 para los test, pues es uno de los ultimos datos que cita en su pregunta, y me sale la duda de que quizas se referia al 80% aun asi el resultado es similar pues yo simplifique los ceros, le dejo algo que pienso se ajusta mas a su pregunta en termino de datos:

- Consumo General -> 10000
- consumo -> 8000

```
        Eficiencia Energetica


Para determinar la eficiencia energetica 
ingrese el Consumo General (en kW): 10000

Ahora ingrese el consumo a comparar: 8000

CONSUMO MEDIO
```

---

le dejo esta captura de internet quizas le sea mas facil de entender lo que le comento:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta, edité la pregunta original para mostrarle un pantallazo. Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Me podría mostar el código que está usando y el que le está dando esos resultados, por favor? No entiendo qué está mal.

Comment: @GermánDiegoGuisasolaPlejo puede ir a http://cpp.sh/ y poner el codigo de su pregunta y ejecutarlo posiblemente obtenga algo similar a lo que yo le muestro, si es asi y el codigo que tiene en su captura es el mismo, a simple vista parece que si, es muy posible que tenga que construir el proyecto de nuevo porque quizas esta ejecutando una version antigua en su ide. Saludos

Comment: Tiene razón, hice lo que me indicó y sí está bien, lo que no entiendo es por qué Code::Blocks me está arrojando valores equivocados.
Edit: No hay forma. Hice un rebuild y me sigue arrojando lo mismo...

Comment: @GermánDiegoGuisasolaPlejo el codigo es el mismo que el que usted dejo, busque en su ide algo como **re-build** o algo similar, **construir de nuevo**, o algo asi, quizas esta ejecutando algun codigo que ha sido construido anteriormente basandose en otro codigo, despues hizo cambios pero no lo construyo con lo que se esta ejecutando un codigo diferente al que usted ve un su pantalla. Saludos

Comment: Justamente eso hice, incluso creé un nuevo proyecto pero no hay forma, sigue arrojándome "CONSUMO BAJO" cuando ingreso 80. Supongo que cambiaré de Code::Blocks a Visual Studio...

Comment: Si, eso hice. Incluso le di a Clean, luego a Build y luego a Run.
También creé un nuevo proyecto pero nada...

Comment: @GermánDiegoGuisasolaPlejo pues no se ahora mismo que puede ser, pues no uso Code::Blocks pero tiene toda la pinta que esta relacionado con lo comentado o similar. que esta ejecutando un binario diferente, quizas a lo largo del dia alguien que use code lo puede ayudar mejor saludos.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61045/discussion-between-german-diego-guisasola-plejo-and-angel-angel).

Answer (score 4):

El problema se encuentra en el tipo de variable utilizado. La gente está acostumbrada a hacer comparaciones al uso:

```
int valor;
std::cin >> valor;
if( valor < 10 )
  // ...
```

Pero con números en coma flotante hay que tener más cuidado y el motivo es que tanto `float` como `double` no poseen una precisión plena, sino que tienen una serie de dígitos *basura*. En el caso de `float`, únicamente los primeros 6 dígitos son representativos, mientras que en el caso de `double` podemos confiar en los primeros 12.

Que haya dígitos basura implica que existen varias representaciones binarias que nos den, de forma efectiva, un mismo número. Así, para un tipo `float`, se entendería que ambos números deberían ser iguales:

```
6 digitos | basura
   1,00000 01
   1,00000 09
```

Y sin embargo el operador de comparación nos diría que los valores son diferentes. Es decir, a la hora de comparar variables en coma flotante tenemos que realizar comparaciones relativas. Esto es, debemos establecer un margen de error, de tal forma que entenderemos que dos variables son iguales si no se supera dicho margen de error.

Por ejemplo, para comparar si el valor de un `float` es igual a 10 deberíamos hacer algo así:

```
float valor;
std::cin >> valor;
if( std::abs(valor - 10) < 1e-6 )
//                         ^^^^ Margen de error
{
  // ...
}
```

Esta característica de la codificación en coma flotante afecta también a los operadores *menor que*, *mayor que*, *menor o igual*, *mayor o igual* y *distinto*. Hay que prestar especial atención a este aspecto, ya que si el valor almacenado está lo suficientemente cerca (se diferencian únicamente en dígitos basura) del valor de referencia el resultado de la comparación puede no ser satisfactorio. Piensa por ejemplo en los valores que he puesto antes:

```
6 digitos | basura
   1,00000 01
   1,00000 09
```

Una operación de mayor o igual debería dar como resultado `true` y, sin embargo, devolverá `false` ya que en primer dígito es, realmente, menor que el segundo. Así mismo, el operador *distinto* `!=` devolverá `true`.

Dicho todo esto, el ejercicio debería quedar más bien así

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  float consumoGeneral = 0;
  float consumo = 0;
  float const error = 1e-5;

  cout << "\t\tEficiencia Energetica" << endl;
  cout << endl << endl;
  cout << "Para determinar la eficiencia energetica \ningrese el Consumo "
          "General (en kW): ";
  cin >> consumoGeneral;
  cout << endl;
  cout << "Ahora ingrese el consumo a comparar: ";
  cin >> consumo;
  cout << endl;

  if( consumoGeneral + error < consumo )
    std:cout << "ALTO CONSUMO DE ENERGIA";
  else if( consumoGeneral * 0.8 - error > consumo )
    std::cout << "CONSUMO MEDIO";
  else
    cout << "CONSUMO BAJO";

  cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

En la primera comparación, a `consumoGeneral` le añadimos un margen de error. Lo que hacemos es asumir que `consumo==consumoGeneral` mientras la diferencia entre ambos sea inferior a `error`, para evitar la incertidumbre, le sumamos el margen de error al consumo.

En la comparación del consumo medio pasa algo similar... solo que ahora resto el margen de error. Ahora se resta porque el operador al que sustituimos es *mayor o igual*, y es precisamente ese *igual* el que obliga a restar el margen de error. Lo que hacemos es incluir el rango `(consumoGeneral-error,consumoGeneral)` en el conjunto válido de valores.